# Duplicate Autocomplete history in firefox textbox

Tags: html, firefox, browser

My log-in page have 2 input field and one password filed.

one of input file has duplicate suggestions on the fire fox but that is not happen in chrome

i want to keep suggestions without duplicate same value as bellow image

[image]

please help to avoid duplicate suggestions

Comment: Clear your browser cache, you should provide as much information as possible, use the guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes i clear cache browser and remove save password but still happen. sorry for my question if you want to any code ill post but im sure my html code was fine. if you have any idea please help to me